# İn desktop and mobile different presentation

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I made a web site but the presentation the page is different berween PC and smartphone.

PC :

[Site - PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cn5qP.jpg)

Smartphone :

[Site - Smartphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxiUw.jpg)

I would that show the same in the smartphone like PC. But in smartphone the buttons is not visible and the image is not in center. How can i do this?

All the code of the page :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/logo2.png">
    <title>Photo - T-Construction</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://bootswatch.com/5/darkly/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .btnfleche{
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body style="background-color: black;height: 100%;width: 100%;">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="window.location.href='realisation.php';" style="float: left;margin: 4%;color: black;">Retour</button>

    <?php

    $ids = intval($_GET["photoid"]);
    $idm = $ids-1;
    $idp = $ids+1;

    if($ids == null){
        header("location:realisation.php");
    }else{

        require 'dbcon.php';

        $getreal = $con -> prepare("select image from realisations where id = ?");
        $getreal -> bindParam(1, $ids);
        $getreal -> execute();
        $donnees = $getreal -> fetchall();
        if($donnees == null){
            header("location:realisation.php");
        }

        ?>

        <div style="width: 100%;height: 100%;"><center><img src="<?php echo($donnees[0]['image']); ?>" width="50%" height="50%" style="width: 50%;height: 50%;margin-top: 5%;margin-right: 5%;"></center>

        <?php

        $getrealm = $con -> prepare("select image from realisations where id = ?");
        $getrealm -> bindParam(1, $idm);
        $getrealm -> execute();
        $donneesm = $getrealm -> fetchall();
        if($donneesm != null){
            ?>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btnfleche" onclick="window.location.href='realphoto.php?photoid=<?php echo($idm); ?>';" style=" display: flex;align-items: center;float: left;color:red;background-color: black;"><h3><--</h3></button>
            <?php
        }

        $getrealp = $con -> prepare("select image from realisations where id = ?");
        $getrealp -> bindParam(1, $idp);
        $getrealp -> execute();
        $donneesp = $getrealp -> fetchall();
        if($donneesp != null){
            ?>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btnfleche" onclick="window.location.href='realphoto.php?photoid=<?php echo($idp); ?>';" style="display: flex;align-items: center;float: right;left: 95%;color:red;background-color: black;"><h3>--></h3></button></div>
            <?php
        }

    }

    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I need your help.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I recommend checking out [mcve] as most of that isn't actually needed to duplicate the problem. Also, your viewport seems complicated why not keep it simple like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`?

Comment: @imvain2 Thanks. The viewport is the same.

Comment: In your `else`-block, you open a div, but you're closing it inside an `if`-statement. So if `if($donneesp != null){` evaluates as false ($donneesp is null), then you never close the div.

Comment: I would post the generated HTML and not the PHP that makes it. The generated HTML/CSS will assist users in checking the HTML/CSS that is affecting the layout.

Comment: @M.Eriksson you are right. I changed the code. Nothing change.

Comment: @imvain2 OK. You are right.